# Give two different kind of edges and keep one non removable with it´s own features

Tags: javascript, css, cytoscape.js

What I´m trying here to do is creating non removable edges. for example I have an edge between **a** and **b** and when I click on one of them the edge should be still visible and his color as well will not changed to red. when I click on node **b** then only one edge should be created to node **c** with red color and same thing for **c** node and so on...

thanks for help in advance.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),
    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        style: {
          content: "data(id)"
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          "curve-style": "bezier",
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
          "visibility": "hidden", 
          "line-color": "#61bffc",
        }
      },
      {
        selector: ".fixededge",
        style: {
          "curve-style": "bezier",
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
          "line-color": "#61bffc",
        }
      },
      {
        selector: ".visible",
        style: {
          "visibility": "visible"
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge.visible",
        style: {
          "visibility": "visible",
        }
      }
    ],
    elements: {
      nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "a"
        }
        
      }, {
        data: {
          id: "b"
        }
      }, {
        data: {
          id: "c"
        }
      }],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          id: "ab",
          source: "a",
          target: "b"
        },
        classes:["visible"]
      }, {
        data: {
          id: "bc",
          source: "b",
          target: "c"
        }
      }]
    },
    layout: {
      name: "grid"
    }
  }));

  cy.on("click", "node", function(event) {
    let connectedEdges = event.target.connectedEdges().style('line-color', 'red');
    connectedEdges.toggleClass("visible");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-popper@1.0.4/cytoscape-popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.0.1/umd/index.all.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.0.1/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a class for this, just like you already do with the visibility. Generally speaking though, you have some weired classes like **.visible** and **.fixedEdge**:

You should clarify, which scope the classes can address, the way you are doing it, a node could have the class **fixedEdge**. Although you would have to manually add that to a node, it is still better to just write something like this instead:

```
{
    selector: "edge.fixed",
    style: {
      "line-color": "#61bffc",
      "target-arrow-color": "#61bffc",
    }
},
{
    selector: "edge.visible",
    style: {
      "visibility": "visible",
    }
}
```

The main difference to your code is a simple if-clause in the event handler. By utilizing the [hasClass()](https://js.cytoscape.org/#ele.hasClass) function, you can query the presence of **.fixed** and simply ignore the following class toggle. Also, I added the **.fixed** class to the edges class list:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),
    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        style: {
          content: "data(id)"
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          "curve-style": "bezier",
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
          "visibility": "hidden",
          "line-color": "red",
          "target-arrow-color": "red",
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge.fixed",
        style: {
          "line-color": "#61bffc",
          "target-arrow-color": "#61bffc",
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge.visible",
        style: {
          "visibility": "visible",
        }
      }
    ],
    elements: {
      nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "a"
        }

      }, {
        data: {
          id: "b"
        }
      }, {
        data: {
          id: "c"
        }
      }],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          id: "ab",
          source: "a",
          target: "b"
        },
        classes: ["visible", "fixed"]
      }, {
        data: {
          id: "bc",
          source: "b",
          target: "c"
        }
      }]
    },
    layout: {
      name: "grid"
    }
  }));

  cy.on("click", "node", function(event) {
    event.target.connectedEdges().each(function(edge) {
      if (!edge.hasClass("fixed")) {
        edge.toggleClass("visible");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-popper@1.0.4/cytoscape-popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.0.1/umd/index.all.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.0.1/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello @Stephan T. could you please see this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636663/activate-cytoscape-cxtmenu-button-under-condition)